# How to store online/in cloud WIFI passwords?

Tags: android, ubuntu, password-manager, wifi

I'm using Ubuntu, and I need a password manager that stores automatically wifi ESSIDs/passwords (such as wap keys) as I save them.
Moreover, it should be import all wifi keys already saved.
Everything should be stored online and accessible from an Android app.

LastPass doesn't work with WIFI passwords (not on Ubuntu, unfortunately).

If you can suggest one such software, please provide documentation for my specific request.

Comment: Those features would require the Android device being rooted (otherwise now access to WiFi passwords already stored on-device, and probably neither to those you enter on-device, at least not via the usual on-board UI). Is that condition acceptable? If so, are paid solutions acceptable (and what would be the price limit)?

Comment: Basically, the passwords will come from Ubuntu (and Android will only act as a client). The best would be Lastpass with a sort of WIFI plugin.

Comment: OK, that clarifies part of it. Still, if a solution would require root, would that be acceptable? I'm not aware of such a solution, but someone else might be. Funnily, a quick check turned up an Android app to sync WiFi passwords cross-device that claims to not require root: [Wi-Fi password reminder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rusdelphi.wifipassword). Don't know what to make of that, but I surely will update [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_config) :)

Comment: What for Ubuntu?

Comment: What about root? You still didn't give that detail. // Besides: I couldn't find any ready-to-use solution for your needs (curious for answers to turn up here). Until then, for hand-made solutions you could check [How To Recover WiFi Passwords Using Linux](//www.lifewire.com/recover-wifi-passwords-with-linux-4120820) on how to obtain the network/password combinations from a Linux machine – and check with our Android sister site for how to access/replace them on Android (there is at least one post on that). There also was a [discussion on ownCloud](//forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=26671).

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understand. I need something for UBUNTU that could save passwords like Lastpass does. It still should offer compile for web sites. Passwords saved this way should be accessible clientside from Android (like Lastpass actually does without root).
To be quick: I need Lastpass alternative that could add wifi storing.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I just doubt such a thing exists, so I thought I at least leave you some pointers to get as close to that as possible. I'm out then, sorry I cannot help you further.